# JPA - Threads: Connection remains open after close

Tags: multithreading, jpa, connection

I'm implementing a Server socket application with Multi-Thread features. In details, when a client connect to the server, the managment of the request is passed to a thread. In this thread I do this steps:

- entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SensorPersistence").createEntityManager();
- MeasurementsManager mm = new      MeasurementsManager(entityManager);
- Measurement meas = new Measurement();
- setting values
- mm.add(meas);
- close entity manager

All works good but after thread ends, the connection on the MySQL is still active. If i terminate the Server application then the connection are closed.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Are you (or your framework) using a connection pool? If you are, it is normal for the connection to remain active between requests.

Comment: Hi, I'm usging Hibernate-JPA and I heard about connection pool but I think that I'm not using connection pool. How can I determine if I am using it? (I'm new with JPA). Thanks.

Comment: Hibernate ships with a default connection pool which, according to the doc, "is in no way intended for production use". So you are most likely using the default pool. I don't know how to be 100% sure though.

Comment: I solved! The problem was that I did not clode the EntityManagerFactory too. Thanks.

Comment: It makes sense since the pool is managed at the factory level. Be aware however that if you close the factory after each query, you are losing all the benefits of the pool. It is common to create the factory when the application starts and close it only when the application terminates.